# How to get the content of a table rows and columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Can anyone give me an idea on how I will count the table column and table row and get the id, attribute and the content of a each cell (the cell is contenteditable). What tools do I have to use?

e.g.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td id='1A' rowspan=2>Rowspan 2</td>
 <td id='1B'>22222</td>
 <td id='1C'>33333</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
   <td id='2B' colspan='2'> Colspan2</td>      
</tr>
<tr>
 <td id='3A' style='color:red'>Whaterver</td>
 <td id='3B' style='font-weight:bold'>Askyourmother</td>
 <td id='3C'>sigh</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I'm using Jquery (Javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of jQuery to get it and then do whatever you want with it.
In this case I just print it in the console.

```
//for each TR...
$('table tr').each(function(){

    //for each TD....
    $(this).find('td').each(function(){
         console.log($(this).text());  //do whatever you want with the text
         console.log($(this).attr('id'));  
         console.log($(this).attr('any_other_attribute'));  
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay. you've erase your comment. . sulker

Answer (score 1):

you can use `jQuery.`

**To get all tr use it as below.**

```
var count = $('table tr').length;
```

above will out put `count` of all the tr inside table.

**To get the ID attribut of `DOM` use `.attr()`**

```
var tableID = $('table').attr('id');
```

above will out-put the `ID` attribute of the `DOM`.

**To get the text inside of `DOM` use `.text()` or `.html()`**

```
var text = $('table tr td').text();
var html = $('table tr td').html();
```

above will out-put the `HTML or TEXT` inside of the selected `DOM`.

Answer (score 0):

use `length` to count tr and `each` to get ids and contents.

```
var table=$('table tr');
var trCount=  table.length;  //count tr
alert('trcount='+trCount);

  $('table tr td').each(function(){
       var tdID=$(this).attr('id'); //get id
       var tdcontent=$(this).text(); //get content
    alert('id='+tdID);  
    alert('content='+tdcontent);  
   }) ;
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/8EHct/)

Comment: hahaha I'd try this on my code with 100 table row and A-Z table columns. . My goodness. . I don't know how many alert that showed up! LOL! :D

Comment: yes ... each td will give u an alert.... try saving it in array ..use that..:).. i used alert just to show you the id and contents.. :)